# Roll Maneuver in SpaceX Demo-2 Launch?

Tags: spacex, rockets, launch

I couldn't see a roll maneuver early in the launch of the demo-2 mission, and this left me wondering if SpaceX skipped the maneuver. Would they do the pitchover without roll?

Also, I've noticed in one of their satellite launches that the roll maneuver they did then came after a small pitchover. I thought you'd roll first and pitchover second, if you do them separately?

Can anyone clarify if SpaceX skips the roll maneuver, and if they don't skip it, do they do it before, during, or after the pitchover? Thanks!